# Destiny XBOX 360 Hard Drive Question

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

I bought Destiny for my son show has XBOX 360 and it stays I need a hard drive.  I inserted an 8GB flash drive to the XBOX and it still says I need a hard drive to play the game.  Please help!!  I tried transferring data to the flash drive and then play the game and it still didn't work.

Comment: How big is this xBox exactly?

Answer (score 4):

It seems USB sticks are not supported.

As mentioned on [Xbox forum](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_one_games/a_-_d/destiny/f/4091/t/1829826.aspx?pi7406=2), on the game case there's a warning:

> NOTE: Xbox 360 Hard Drive is required. USB Storage is not supported.

Also, official [Xbox 360 game page](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Destiny/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802415608f8) on the second page of Overview states:

> Hard drive required

There's a post on [official Bungie forum](http://www.bungie.net/en/Forum/Post/69007167/0/0) as well:

> You cannot run Destiny off of external flash drives/hard drives -
>   regardless of storage space, it must be an officially supported hard
>   drive from the console manufacturer.

So your best bet seems to buy an Xbox HDD. That prerequisite is most likely because of Destiny being online-only game with periodic updates, so it requires both good transfer speed and disk space (update before Dark Below was over 2GB for example).

Answer (score 1):

you cant use a flash drive you need a xbox hard drive i had the same problem